# X-axis goes farther than last time interval

Tags: matlab

If I set a time interval, `[0 10]`, and I plot something according to that time interval, `plot(t, y())`, then the graph will have its x-axis going all the way to 11.

It used to not do this. It used to produced a better fitting graph, but now it produces a graph with white space attached to the end of the graph between points 10 and 11.

I must have accidentally changed a setting. How do I get the plot function to best fit the graph?

Comment: I have an old version of MATLAB, so I don't know if this is up to date: Go in your figure into the menu `edit->Axes properties`. There you can set the limits of `x` and `y` either manually or choose `auto` which will fit your axes automatically.

Comment: Please have a look at [Setting Axis Parameters](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f6-7929.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a polished plot, you almost always have to adjust the plot axis limits yourself.  Some useful commands:

```
axis tight;         %Squeeze the data as closely as possible
xlim([xMin xMax]);  %Adjust the x axis limits, do not touch the y limits
ylim([yMin yMax]);  
axis([xMin xMax yMin yMax]);  %Adjust all axis limits
```

You your case you would probably add a line like this to your code:

```
xlim([min(t) max(t)]);
```

Or, if you know that t is sorted (very common)

```
xlim(t([1 end]));
```